# Private base class affects member access via template friend function and template method in child class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

First of all, sorry for the lengthy title. I encountered an issue, where the existence of a private base of the same type as a member shadows access to the member in a child class but not outside the child class definition. Look at the following code:

```
 struct PrivateBase {};

 struct Base : private PrivateBase {
   // Member accessors.
   PrivateBase* GetPrivateBase() { return &a; }

   template<typename T>
   T* GetPrivateBase() { return &a; }

   // Free function accessors.
   friend PrivateBase* FreeGetPrivateBase(Base* b) { return &(b->a); }

   template<typename T>
   friend T* FreeGetPrivateBase(Base* b);

  private:
   // This member has nothing to do with the PrivateBase base class.
   PrivateBase a;
 };

 template<typename T>
 T* FreeGetPrivateBase(Base* b) { return &(b->a); }

 struct Child : public Base {
   void SomeFunc() {
     // Works!1!!.
     GetPrivateBase();

     // Doesn't work.
     //GetPrivateBase<PrivateBase>(); // (1)

     // Works!1!!.
     FreeGetPrivateBase(this);

     // Doesn't work.
     //FreeGetPrivateBase<PrivateBase>(this);
   }
 };

 int main() {
   Child c;

   // Works!1!!.
   c.GetPrivateBase<PrivateBase>();

   // Works!1!!.
   FreeGetPrivateBase<PrivateBase>(&c);

   return 0;
 }
```

I've tried to compile this both, with g++-4.8.4 and clang++-3.7.1. With clang and (1) uncommented I get:

```
minimal.cc:30:20: error: 'PrivateBase' is a private member of 'PrivateBase'
    GetPrivateBase<PrivateBase>();
                   ^
minimal.cc:3:15: note: constrained by private inheritance here
struct Base : private PrivateBase {
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
minimal.cc:1:8: note: member is declared here
struct PrivateBase {};
       ^
```

The fun fact is that access to `a` works outside of Child and inside Child with the non-templated accessors. It also works inside Child with the templated accessors if I get rid of the private base class.
I would love to blame it on the compiler but unconventionally enough both contenders seem to agree. Could anybody explain the interplay between templated accessors, child scope and private base class? - Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name lookup is done before access checking. Unqualified name lookup for `PrivateBase` within a member function of `Child` finds the [*injected class name*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Injected_class_name) of the `PrivateBase` base class, which is then found to be private, hence the error.

Using something like `GetPrivateBase<::PrivateBase>();` inside `SomeFunc()` fixes the problem, because qualified name lookup now finds `PrivateBase` as a member of the global namespace, where it is accessible.

This is also why the calls in `main` work: `main` is not a member function, so unqualified name lookup for `PrivateBase` finds the namespace member.